# self.variable_name vs variable_name in method inside python class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Both versions of the code are working. I am trying to understand the difference between self.data_as_csv vs data_as_csv.

In which scenario each of them is useful over the another.

**Version 1:**

```
import pandas as pd   
class test_class:
    def __init__(self, inputFile):
        self.file = inputFile

    def generate_csv(self):
        self.data_as_csv = pd.read_csv(self.file)
        return self.data_as_csv

x = test_class("out.csv")    
df = x.generate_csv()        
print(df)
```

**Version 2:**

```
import pandas as pd   
    class test_class:
        def __init__(self, inputFile):
            self.file = inputFile

        def generate_csv(self):
            data_as_csv = pd.read_csv(self.file)
            return data_as_csv

    x = test_class("out.csv")    
    df = x.generate_csv()        
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

using as self, you have access to the variable like this, so if you needed access to the data from the class, it would be useful in that case:

```
x.data_as_csv

Out[1456]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [P234, Dog, Billy, No, No.1, D32432432, Lost, 01/09/2018, 28/08/2019, return to owner, 123 Fake Drive, LS34 1LE]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 1):

using `self.` will allow you to access to this variable from any method of your class, that means u can have your 'global' variable available only in current class and only for current instance